Why is Stam Mishna attributed to R' Meir, a fourth-generation Tannah?
It is widely accepted that "Stam (unattributed) Mishna" is Rabbi Meir's (c. 150 CE, Sanhedrin 86a) who was one of five students of Rabbi Akiva (c. 135 CE).
I struggle to understand the implications of this statement:

Why is it stated by R' Yohanan who lived some 70-100 years later and not R' Meir's contemporaries?
Was it a hypothesis and the basis for the resolution of Mishnaic contradictions ("Let's assume that all Stam Mishna is aligned with R' Meir's views"), or a historical statement?
Why the bulk of the Mishnah is attributed to the fourth-generation Tannah, and not the first-generation, like Hillel, Shammay, and more, or even earlier, like Zugos, when there were no disagreements?
Why then, no Mishna is attributed to Moses and Jewish never-broken tradition?


For your last question Mishnayos are the arrangement of halacha in a specific way meant to be memorized. This is the same idea with brysos and toseftos. Since Moshe didn't arrange halacha into these formulas they wouldn't be attributed to him but clearly halacha from from har Sinai as a whole and we do see the phrase halacha Moshe misinai

@Dude What do you mean by "Moshe didn't arrange halacha into these formulas"?

Exactly that. The statements of mishnah, tosefta, and brysa are the halachos expressed in specific words the way they were taught by specific rabbis.

I don't get "and not R' Meir's contemporaries?" His contemporaries didn't write our mishnayos, R' Yehudah Hanasi did. R' Yochanan was one of his students and one of the first to deal with the Mishnah as an independent object of study.

"and not the first-generation, like Hillel, Shammay..." This was the whole point of creating the Mishnah. Israel was losing track of the Oral Torah due to oppression; students weren't able to get the training they needed. We started to have a lot of disagreement, so Rebbi compiled all the sides to organize things. You don't need a mishnah from the days when everyone agreed. What you do often get is an old accepted mishnah (שתי שורות במרתף) along with the statements of the last tannaim who are arguing about understanding it.

"Why then, no Mishna is attributed to Moses " Same answer.

@MichoelR I don't understand how you see it. Rambam says everyone privately wrote down their Mishnayos. You wrote, "you often get an old accepted Mishnah". How otherwise could Rebbeh pick R' Meir's ones?

@MichoelR FOllowing your comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/144806/tannaic-sources-for-the-need-to-compile-the-mishna

@AlBerko The Rambam says that they made private notes, for themselves. Those were neither published nor (probably) taught directly to students.

@AlBerko That's a discussion for that other thread. I'm just repeating here the standard understanding.

Re:

no Mishna is attributed to Moses

The Bet Yosef (O"H 50) writes from the Ra'ah (Brachot 31a) that the chapter Eizehu Mekoman (Z'vachim 5) was said by Moshe. It is attributed to the GRA (P'ninei m'Shulhan haGRA) that this can be deduced from the language "לפנים מן הקלעים" (within the curtains) that shows up in these Mishnayot a couple times. Only the Mishkan had curtains and not the Bet Hamikdash which the Mishna generally discusses.
IMHO, there are parts of other individual Mishnayot which are clearly from Moshe. For example Negaim 7:1 which discusses if one had Tzara'at from before Matan Torah. Similarly, in Bava Kama 5:7 regarding animals going on Har Sinai which only applied while they were there.

On that note the Mishna's lack of order (discussing cases before defining a term) always seemed to me as there was an original Mishna - teaching, said by the teacher, and that a student asked clarification on a point. The explanation was then added on and then taught by future students that way.

A nice Drush (maybe a comment). IMHO, This doesn't answer why wasn't the rest of the Stam Mishna tried to be attributed to Moses. Can you please address this issue?

The main answer is ydj. Ribbi choose Rabbi meirs wording like the Rambam wrote that Ribbi was a master linguist and he wrote super concisely. my theory is that all mishnayot started from Moshe, just that things were added on (sometimes a little awkwardly). The only full chapter was Z5 but there would be a line here and there from Moshe

See my other questions https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109880/why-didnt-rebbi-compile-all-existing-pieces-of-the-oral-tradition-into-the-mish. Apparently, Rebbeh didn't write anything, he probably compiled som known Mishnayos and promoted them with his political power. Also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95082/not-being-precise-rashi-in-recording-the-oral-torah. Mishna does not appear to be what you might think.

my answer to your first post is the answer to the second too. Ribbi chose Ribbi Meir's mishna since they had the best wording. I would guess he was the one who wrote the non-stam machlokot that were added on to stam. Parenthetically, not all mishna was ribbi meir either, its also a generalization. Bet Hamikdash Mishnayot were from Ribbi Eliezer ben Yaakov https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.16a.1, a Kohen who served in the Bet Hamikdash and wrote them down (taught them?) after the destruction

re: political power. I think youre mistaken. the later generations chose who to follow. Some of Ribbis own students argued on his style of 6 sedarim and wrote their version of the oral Torah based on the torah, the sifra and sifri. Ribbi's won.

We do see his predecessors like Rabban Gamliel force Chachamim to accept their "political" decisions, like in Brochos about Ma'ariv or B"M about Akhnay's own. This is why in R"H tractate they agreed that the calendar (months and years) would be approved by Rebbeh who approved them with local authorities in Syria. So Rebbeh did have power that he probably used to promote his version of the Mishnah. In the long run, Rebbeh sort of lost, the Mishna is still attributed to him out of respect, but he doesn't play a central role in it.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

R. Sherira Gaon explains in his Iggeres, Ch. 3 "Mishna" (translation R. Nosson Dovid Rabinovich):
"Every anonymous Mishna is [the teaching of] R. Meir.  But he did not create them from his own heart. Rather, R. Meir had a certain way of teaching the mishnayos (1) to his disciples; and Rebbe (R. Yehudah ha Nassi) chose and established this way (2) to teach [the mishnayos] to everyone. R. Meir had received his way of learning [the Mishna] from his teacher, R. Akiva; and R. Akiva had received it from his teachers, the earlier sages. This we say (Sanhedrin 86a):

R. Yochanan said: " An anonymous Mishna is R. Meir. An anonymous Tosefta is R. Nechemiah. An anonymous Sifra is R. Yehuda (bar Ila'i) An anonymous Sifrei is R. Shimon (b. Yochai). And all of them taught in the way of R. Akiva.

These baraissos of Tosefta, Sifra, and Sifrei were taught by the earlier sages. Then R. Yehuda, R. Nechemiah, and R. Shimon came, and each made his own compilation of [the baraissos]. Sifra [was compiled by R. Yehuda]; Tosefta - by R. Nechemiah; and Sifrei - by R. Shimon; and the Mishna by R. Meir. And all of them follow the method of R. Akiva, for all of them were disciples of R. Akiva."
Rebbe, Rabbeinu haKadosh, R. Yehuda haNassi  - he was well versed in all existing halachic presentations, Rebbi mastered 13 approaches to the laws (Nedarim 41a) as discussed here; he also can be considered a student of many rabbis. It was his choice to use approach of Rabbi Meir, because he found it the most suitable for a kind of a code that Mishna is supposed to be: fairly generic, yet detailed enough. Says gemara Eruvin 13b in praise of R. Meir:

On the topic of Rabbi Meir and his Torah study, the Gemara cites an additional statement. Rabbi Aḥa bar Ḥanina said: It is revealed and known before the One Who spoke and the world came into being that in the generation of Rabbi Meir there was no one of the Sages who is his equal. Why then didn’t the Sages establish the halakha in accordance with his opinion? It is because his colleagues were unable to ascertain the profundity of his opinion. He was so brilliant that he could present a cogent argument for any position, even if it was not consistent with the prevalent halakha. As he would state with regard to a ritually impure item that it is pure, and display justification for that ruling, and likewise he would state with regard to a ritually pure item that it is impure, and display justification for that ruling. The Sages were unable to distinguish between the statements that were halakha and those that were not.
It was taught in a baraita: Rabbi Meir was not his name; rather, Rabbi Nehorai was his name. And why was he called by the name Rabbi Meir? It was because he illuminates [meir] the eyes of the Sages in matters of the halakha. And Rabbi Nehorai was not the name of the tanna known by that name; rather, Rabbi Neḥemya was his name, and some say: Rabbi Elazar ben Arakh was his name. And why was he called by the name Rabbi Nehorai? It is because he enlightens [manhir] the eyes of the Sages in matters of the halakha.
The Gemara relates that Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi said: The fact that I am more incisive than my colleagues is due to the fact that I saw Rabbi Meir from behind, i.e., I sat behind him when I was his student. Had I seen him from the front, I would be even more incisive, as it is written: “And your eyes shall see your teacher” (Isaiah 30:20). Seeing the face of one’s teacher increases one’s understanding and sharpens one’s mind.
And the Gemara stated that Rabbi Abbahu said that Rabbi Yoḥanan said: Rabbi Meir had a disciple, and his name was Sumakhus, who would state with regard to each and every matter of ritual impurity forty-eight reasons in support of the ruling of impurity, and with regard to each and every matter of ritual purity forty-eight reasons in support of the ruling of purity.


(1) Each Tanna had his own style and order of teaching the mishnayos.
(2) R. Meir was his teacher (Eruvin 13b, Yebamos 93a). This point was discussed here in the comments that R. Yehuda ha Nassi did not study with Rabbi Meir, but that he studied his work.

You just state the obvious, but don't address the question of why. Yes, we already know that Rebbeh picked R"M's Mishna. Why not R' Akiva's who had 5 disciples - they all had different Mishnayos probably, as we see in Braisas?

@AlBerko ok, I am adding additional paragraph
