Tannaic sources for the need to compile the Mishna
Following "Why-didnt-rebbi-compile-all-existing-pieces-of-the-oral-tradition-into-the-mishna", a common explanation for the compilation of the Mishna is that "Israel was losing track of the Oral Torah due to oppression; students weren't able to get the training they needed and they started to have a lot of disagreement".
In my understanding, such posterior claims are apologetic rather than explanational, they try to justify an existing phenomenon, rather than provide a factual cause.
I'm not aware of any sign of authorship in the Mishnah, or a need from the earlier Tannayim to unify the sources, e.g. there are fierce arguments between the House of Hillel and the House of Shammay but nobody proposes writing down a unifying version for future generations.
Is there any textual support for that claim from the generation of Rabbi Yehuda or earlier?


Introduction:

Beis Hillel and Beis Shammai are before Rebbi, and they are "unified" in Mishna (ie: both opinions recorded) - similarly their opinions are already Halachically decided who is correct.
Many times Rebbi is declaring in Mishna (and Gemara follows suit) the Halachic opinion and those who argue for a number of reasons (one is to specify the exact argument, and often that it was decided, and no other opinion was held on that topic).

Answer:

Authorship of the Mishna is an "on going" process before Rebbi, you can see that in the following:
Chagiga 2a Where it says "Here is the first Mishna and here is the later Mishna" It is explaining why the word "הכל" is used; possibly, because it came to include something according to Beit Hillel and subsequently Beis Hillel changed their opinion and agreed with Beit Shamai (see there); however, once the Mishna was memorized with the word "הכל" it was not changed subsequently. Either to make note of the change of opinion or because it was already memorized, or perhaps הכל had another reason for being there (as the Gemara also states). However, you can see there is a specific authorship and system for authorship. Even before Rebbi it was memorized.
There are other examples of systemized authorship before Rebbi that Rebbi included in his unified version. Though I cannot recall them all off the top of my head.
A simple proof is Chagiga 14a where it states:

בעלי משנה כגון ר׳׳י בן תימא וחביריו. פליגו בה רב פפא ורבנן חד אמר שש מאות סדרי משנה וחד אמר שבע מאות סדרי משנה
"Masters of Mishna" Like R' Yehuda ben Tema and his colleagues. Rav Pappa and The Rabbis argue: One says [they mastered] 600 orders of Mishna and One says 700 orders of Mishna

It seems clear that there were different "versions" and although there might have been "many" they were distinct sets. Presumably with a lot of overlap - but nevertheless distinct style/system of teaching the same Oral Law.
If they had different actual laws, Rebbi would need to include them either way. They would exist as Baraisos or Toseftas but we don't see any hint of that.
Also since they aren't individual Mishnas and rather called sets, meaning they were arranged and systemized; otherwise there would be an infinite and wouldn't be called a "set", rather it would be listed as number of Mishnayot on a topic - hopefully the above made sense.
Hopefully this helps you in a way understanding that the Mishnayot were systematically authored for memorization, that they existed before Rebbi, and that Rebbi simply chose or crafted one system for everybody, lest you mix two different styles/systems for example. And so that Rebbi could include the agreed upon Halachic decisions until that time.

This is an ongoing discussion. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60565/what-was-rabbi-yehuda-hanassis-role-in-compiling-the-mishnah

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/143676/what-books-could-be-found-in-rabbi-judahs-library/143818#143818

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109880/why-didnt-rebbi-compile-all-existing-pieces-of-the-oral-tradition-into-the-mish

and a few other places if you make search on this forum.

One can start investigating the origin of the Midrash Eleh Ezkerah, which separately records the event of tragic execution of the 10 Jewish Sages, the major tannaim, by the Roman Imperial government. The same event is also recorded in Eicha Rabba and Midrash Tehilim. While these are amoraic and post-Amoraic sources, already the tanna Elazar haKalir wrote a kinna ארזי הלבנון/Arzei haLevanon, executions of these tannaim are mentioned in the gemara and also ashkenazi Yom Kippur liturgy (אמיץ כח/Amitz Koach). The object of the Midrash is not only the description executions, but the fact that the Roman government expressed interest in Judaism and the Torah and the end result was erasing the names of the core Jewish Sages. For example, Gemara Gittin 56a records conversion of emperor Nero to Judaism, which is unconfirmed historically. What is similar to? The development of Christianity.
If one compares the story of Kamtza and Bar Kamtza in Gittin 55b, one can find a strong correlation to the story of the so called Apostolic Council of Jerusalem described in the New Testament Acts 15-17. This was a moment where the the reformers of Jewish law (Saducees, Boethusians, and others) split into two groups: one side sought rebellion against Rome headed by James (brother of Jesus) and the other side - Paul, who advocated peace with Romans. In the aftermath the followers of James wanted to kill Paul, who actually went to contact the Roman emperor Nero via Epaphroditus. The Roman documents also mention an official with such a name. I will not speculate, whether or not Christianity was a project of the Roman government, while they certainly created new religious cults in every country that they occupied combining Roman and local deities. However, the reading verses of the Scripture in a way that is devoid of tradition (i.e. by cutting the chain of tradition via erasing the names of the core tannaim), by abolishing mitzvos and subplanting the machshavah with hellenist neoplatonic philosophy certainly required that the text like the Mishna be developed.
Therefore, the real question is why the Mishna has not been put to writing prior to those events. Jewish people, like many other nations during the same time shifted from prophetic solutions to more legalistic solutions of the disputs. As discussed here in connection with development of the Mishna, Netziv in the introduction to the Ha’amek Sh’alah to Sheiltos of Rav Hai Gaon (translated as "The Path of Torah") explained that holiness of the Temple somehow allowed the Sanhedrin to arrive at the correct psak without systematically developing generic legal system. Thus, destruction of the Temple and development of Christianity are the real reasons for the need of development of the Mishna.

+1 very impressive, thank you. My guts disagree but I liked your way of thinking. Here's what I think. Jesus was [associated with] an adherent and observant Pharisee, despite being depicted later as having Halachic disagreements with some of them. He was executed for insurgence. His brother James continued his tradition and was also executed for the same reason. [... I don't have anything coming to mind until] Rabbi Akiva joined Bar Kochba in another revolt against the Romans. So, how pacifistic were the Pharisee leaders? Were they really executed for their Torah?

Since you mentioned Christianity, one thing we learn from them is how the narrative is changed, rewritten, and "bettered" with every following generation. I remember studying the story of Ben Netina (I posted a question here) in Kiddushin, where in different sources the payment of the sages grows from 600 in earlier Midrashim to 600K. So it's reasonable to assume we suffer from the same disease. As you mentioned, and as I point out consistently, we can't consider later sources explanatory for earlier events.

@AlBerko Christianity stems from Saducee system of halacha not Phariceee. The Zealots / Sicarii who fought with Romans were Saducees. The Pharicees were friendly to Romans. Only after development of Christianity the Pharicees separated.

This is why I was specifically asking for contemporary or earlier sources, that show the earlier rabbis like the Zugis or the first three generations of Tannoyim suffered from the lack of written Oral law.

WHOT??? According to the NT, Jesus was fighting the Seducee corruption in the Temple turning tables and calling people to overthrow their rule.

I think the answers to the questions like this become quite involved and require serious scholarship in 2nd Temple Judaism before we could venture further.

@AlBerko No. The Temple and the Sanchedrin were controled by the Pharicees since the time of the Roman occupation. Josephus in Antiquities states that. Rabbi Yishmael Kohein Gadol was a Pharicee!!!! The Saducees rulled the Temple with Hashmonaim prior to arrival of Romans. The problem was the Bar Kamtza sect of Saducees which colluded with Romans behind the back of the Pharicees and which included very rich families.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Hmmm... the NT in Matthew 23 records him stating to his followers that the law is with the Pharisees... He rebukes the Saducees in Matthew 22.... It's pretty clear he claimed to be a Pharisee. It's also clear they looked up to them. I'm not even sure how this is debatable.

@msj121 thank you. However, this detail does not change the picture. Maybe there were also the Pharicees who became early Christians. I added "and others."

@YDJ My comment is in regard to your thread, where you are claiming that Christianity comes from the Saducees (or their system), which on first blush makes little sense since Christian sources are anti-saducee and pro-pharisee.... And yes, most early Christians (including Jesus) claim to be Pharisee....

@msj121 that could have been the case and could have been written. I heard from lectures by Lawrence Schiffman that Christianity is connected to Saducees. The leaders of Christianity in the NT appear as sicarii, zealots clearly representing the Saducees. Robert Eisenman also showed that they were Saducees. Pharicees always cooperated with Rome. There is a theory of Roman provenance suggesting that Christianity was created by Rome with Jewish help as a way to pacify the rebelious Saducees which turned their leaders upside down.

@msj121 Why would the Pharicees, who had BhM and Sanhedrin under the Romans need to reform their faith, as Christians clearly did?

@YDJ Many many possibilities... 1). It was a sect. Why is any Chassidus different? 2). Peter was from the Sanhedrin and changed it (this has been written about - who knows...). 3). They started a new religion 4). Rome co-opted the religion 5). Paul wanted to appeal to non-Jews 6). Main Pharisees abandoned it like Bar Kochba after his death.... Any of these is sufficient.

@YDJ Sadly Schiffman is likely coming from the Dead Sea Scrolls being Saducees and a precursor to Christianity. Unlikely by most pro and anti Christian scholars as far as I can tell. I can find you many scholars that study NT and Christianity including Rabbis who will tell you they were Pharasitic. Like Rabbi Skobac etc... The idea of them being Saducees makes so little sense according to Christianity and NT itself.... There is nothing doctrinal in Pharisees to bow to Rome, Rebbe Akiva didn't. That is a bad argument imo.

@msj121 Not at all. Rabbi Akiva lived at a different time when Christianity became the enemy of all Judaism. Josephus says that leaders of pharisees opened gates of Jerusalem to Romans.

@YDJ you misunderstand... there is nothing doctrinal in Pharisee law to be pro/anti Rome, it makes no difference - except if you are a Messiah who will redeem the Jews. That cannot be an argument for or against Jesus being a Saducee or Pharisee. Rebbe Akiva expecting a true Messiah became pro Independence and therefore anti Rome. Nothing pro or anti Pharisee there. Being militaristic against Rome is no barometer at all to sect.... Rome was pro Saducee - many Saducees were pro Rome unlike Jesus. Also Pharisees didn't control BHM at the time from what I've read....

Rabbi Yishmael kohen gadol was not a pharisee? Nassi R. Shimon ben Gamliel was not a pharisee?
